# Why is insert operation slower than search/delete in Binary Search Tree, considering that all should be around O(logn)

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I've implemented *BST* to compare to others objects types, **as Map, {} and Array.**
But the weird thing is that insertion in *BST* takes too long, but search and delete operations in *BST* is faster than in any other data type.

I'm guessing that is due to many instances of Node, but i don't even sure if that makes sense..

```js
export class BinarySearchTree{
    constructor(root = null){
        this.root = root;
        this.length = 1;
    }
    
    search(key){
        let cur_node = this.root;
        while(true){
            if(cur_node === null || cur_node === undefined) return null;
            if(cur_node.key === key) return cur_node;
            if(key < cur_node.key) cur_node = cur_node.left;
            else cur_node = cur_node.right;
        }
    }
    
    add(key, value = key){
        const new_node = new Node(key, value);
        let cur_node = this.root;
        let parent_node = null;
        if(!this.root){
            this.root = new_node;
            return;
        }

        while(true){
            if(cur_node === null) break;
            parent_node = cur_node;
            if(parent_node.key === key) return;
            if(key < cur_node.key) cur_node = cur_node.left;
            else cur_node = cur_node.right;
        }
        const side = key < parent_node.key ? 'left' : 'right';
        parent_node[side] = new_node;
        this.length++;
    }
    
    delete(key){
        let cur_node = this.root;
        let parent_node = null;
        
        while(true){
            if(cur_node === null || cur_node.key === key) break;
            parent_node = cur_node;
            if(key < cur_node.key) cur_node = cur_node.left;
            else cur_node = cur_node.right;
        }
        
        let children = cur_node.getChildren();
        const side = parent_node !== null ? parent_node.getChildByKey(key)[0] : 'root';
        
        if(children.length === 0) parent_node[side] = null;
        else if(children.length === 1) parent_node[side] = children[0][1];
        else if(children.length === 2){
            const min_node_map = this.minNode(cur_node.right);
            cur_node.key = min_node_map.get('min').key;
            cur_node.value = min_node_map.get('min').value;
            min_node_map.get('parent').left = null;
        }
        this.length--;
        
    }
    
    minNode(node = this.root){
        let parent_node = null;
        let cur_node = node;
        while(cur_node.left) {
            parent_node = cur_node;
            cur_node = cur_node.left;
        }
        const map = new Map();
        map.set('min', cur_node);
        map.set('parent', parent_node);
        return map;
    }
    
}
export class Node{
    constructor(key, value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
    
    getChildByKey(key){
        return this.getChildren().find(x => x[1].key === key);
    }
    
    getChildren(){
        const map = new Map();
        map.set('left', this.left);
        map.set('right', this.right);
        return [...map].filter(x => x[1] !== null);
    }
}
```

```js
import { BinarySearchTree } from "./binary-search-tree.js";
const INTERACTIONS = 999999;
//random keys
const random_values = new Array(INTERACTIONS);
for(let i = 0; i < INTERACTIONS; i++)random_values[i] = random(0, INTERACTIONS);
//just to test SEARCH
const SPECIAL_KEY = 1234567;
random_values[Math.floor((random_values.length - 1)/2)] = SPECIAL_KEY;
const item = 'any constant data';

const show = () => {
    let arr = [];
    console.log('array');
    performance('insert', () => {
        for(let i = 0; i < INTERACTIONS; i++)
    arr.push(random_values[i])
    });
    performance('search', () => arr.find(x => x === SPECIAL_KEY));
    performance('delete', () => arr.splice(arr.indexOf(SPECIAL_KEY), 1));
    
    const obj = {};
    console.log(`obj`);
    performance('insert', () => {
        for(let i = 0; i < INTERACTIONS; i++)
        obj[random_values[i]] = item
    });
    performance('search', () => obj[SPECIAL_KEY]);
    performance('delete', () => delete obj[SPECIAL_KEY]);
    
    const map = new Map();
    console.log(`map`);
    performance('insert', () => {
        for(let i = 0; i < INTERACTIONS; i++)
        map.set(random_values[i], item)
    });
    performance('search', () => map.get(SPECIAL_KEY));
    performance('delete', () => map.delete(SPECIAL_KEY));
    
    const bst = new BinarySearchTree();
    console.log(`binary search tree`);
    performance('insert', () => {
        for(let i = 0; i < INTERACTIONS; i++)
        bst.add(random_values[i], item)
    });
    performance('search', () => bst.search(SPECIAL_KEY).value);
    performance('delete', () => bst.delete(SPECIAL_KEY));
}

show();

function random(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
function performance(title, callback){
    const start_time = process.hrtime();
    callback();
    const end_time = process.hrtime(start_time);
    console.log(`${title} ending... ${end_time} seconds`);
}
```

Comment: `O(log n)` says nothing about concrete speed. Don't forget about the arbitrary constant factor.

Comment: I understand, but it's a difference around 20 seconds compared to the others inserts. And all values are random to the binary tree, there may be something wrong don't you think?

Comment: Each `add()` has to create a `Node` object, which is more expensive than just assigning an integer to an element of a collection. Try comparing with `arr.push(new Node(random_values[i]))`

Comment: Good suggestion, the biggest difference was at **{}** insertion, from _.5~1.2_ to _7~7.4_. But in array it was a slight time addition (~.45)...
And actually this BST only allows non-repeated values, otherwise, it will ignore.

Comment: *"considering that all should be around O(logn)"*: time complexity and execution time have little in common. One O(logn) algorithm may spend 0.1 sec on a certain operation, while another O(logn) algorithm may spend 2 hours on it. That is not a contradiction. Time complexity says something about asymptotic behaviour, not about the execution time for a certain input size.

Comment: But when the value is large as it is, we can see the actual algorithm's performance, what means only one input, is by itself relatively slow in time execution at least, right? This was what i thought, I've tested small values (0 to 99999) and BST insert was almost faster than all others insertions.. Then the actual 'execution time' is in quadric form?

Comment: No, you cannot conclude anything about time complexity by doing such tests. If your instructor told you that this is the way to find out about time complexity, they are wrong. Time complexity is proven with a mathematical proof, not by tests. Literally, execution time can be anything... it says *nothing* about time complexity. There are algorithms with a very good time complexity, but nobody uses them, because in practical cases the execution time is unacceptable.

Comment: Would be good having a instructor. ["Saying that an algorithm is O(n) means that the execution time is bounded by some constant times n. Write this as c*n. If the size of the collection doubles, then the execution time is c*(2n)"](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~sinisa/courses/OSU/CS261/CS261_Textbook/Chapter04.pdf). Considering this, any function of log2(n) will decrease it's Y axis while X increases, so i don't finding out an 'acceptable' reason why the time is getting much higher with large inputs